# There was an error connecting to iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud

When I go to the iCloud screen on my iPhone I get a "Verification Failed. There was an error connecting to iCloud."

[image]

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Are you able to browse the Internet?  The first step would be to verify that you have connectivity to the Internet.  Next, restart your phone.  See if the issue persists.

Comment: Hi, I edited your post and removed your personal Information (email).

Comment: @Ruskes - good catch, but it has been out there at least a month and is still viewable in the edit history. The upside is because it’s an mage, it’s unlikely to have been picked up by site scraping bots

Answer (score 1):

This means you don't have an active internet connection to access iCloud. From the picture, I can see you're not connected to WiFi but using a cellular network. To access iCloud and it's relative Settings you need to make sure:

- Mobile Data is on
- You have enabled Mobile Data for Settings

**To enable Mobile Data:**

1. Go to Settings
2. Mobile Data
3. Toggle the switch at the top

**To turn on Mobile Data for Settings:**

1. Go to Settings
2. Mobile Data
3. Go to Settings and toggle the switch so it is green

Comment: You don't need WiFi to connect to iCloud, it also works over cellular (the screenshot shows LTE which includes data).

Comment: @nohillside my answer is saying that possibly their data for settings is off

Comment: It might be better to clarify this with a comment beneath the question, and provide the answer in case it actually *is* the problem. With data turned off you might not even get that kind of error.